# Do iOS and OSX use the same Objective-C runtime?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, objective-c-runtime

The question is in the title. I have to write about the iOS runtime environment and was wondering if it uses the same runtime environment as OS X?

Comment: One example: http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2013/09/24/objc_explain_Non-pointer_isa.html

Comment: @AndrewMedico why/how is that helpful here? ;)

Comment: id say iOS runtime == OS X 64 bit runtime but I don't have any proof

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "same" and "runtime environment".  It's fairly certain that the implementations for many of the Cocoa classes are shared (though likely with liberal use of `#ifdef`).  Clearly, though, the close-to-the-hardware and close-to-the-OS code must be different to suit the associated differences.

Answer (score 3):

The Objective-C 2.0 runtime library ("modern runtime") is used by iOS Apps and all 64 bit Mac OS X Apps. All other applications use "legacy" ObjC runtime (32 bit Mac OS X Apps).
The concrete implementation is slightly different for iOS and Mac OS X, of course.

[Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/ObjCRuntimeGuide.pdf)

Comment: iOS has classes that OSX does not, and vice-versa.

Comment: Framework classes are not the same thing as the Objective-C runtime environment. The fact that they're different is completely irrelevant.